What does "exclusive of other beings" mean?
from Commentaries on the Law of England by William Blackstone
“The Earth, and all things herein, are the general property of mankind, exclusive of other beings, from the immediate gift of the creator"
I don't understand "exclusive of other beings" meaning in this sentence?

Firstly you need to bear in mind that this was written in the 1760s when ideas about the universe and our place in it were very different. What he means is any living things other than humans. This would have been understood at the time as referring to the biblical placing of the Earth under human dominion. He probably would have seen this as excluding other earthly animals, and possibly supernatural creatures (angels, demons, etc.) although the timing (right in the enlightenment) means that these ideas were not as set as they would have been a hundred years earlier.

Thanks for your answer
